# C - Off by one error

Tags: c

in the following simple reverse function I'm always off by one, meaning the first character passed in is never printed last like it should be:

```
  void reverse(char * c)
{
    if(*c != '\0')
    {
        reverse(++c);
        printf("%c", *c);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

yet when I change the call to reverse to be c+1, everything works fine.  Any ideas as to why, the unary pre-increment operator should be doing exactly the same as c + 1.  I know a recursive function isn't the best performing way to go about this problem but I'm just experimenting at the moment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `c+1` does *not* change `c` whereas `++c` *does.*

Think about this when `c` is pointing to address `1234`:

```
reverse(++c);      // c is now 1235 and you pass that.
printf("%c", *c);  // so we print the second character at 1235.
```

With the `c+1` version:

```
reverse(c+1);      // c is still 1234 but you pass 1235.
printf("%c", *c);  // so we print the first character at 1234.
```

---

For what it's worth, your `reverse` function is needlessly complicated.The `else return` is redundant and I personally prefer recursion calls that check terminating conditions first since I've often found these are usually easier for compilers to do tail-end recursion optimisations on.

The following complete test program shows you the way I'd do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse (char *c) {
    if (*c == '\0') return;
    reverse (c + 1);
    putchar (*c);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        reverse (argv[i]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running this with `testprog hello goodbye` gives you:

```
olleh
eybdoog
```

Answer (score 4):

No the unary pre-increment is not the same like addition by one.

`f(++c)` is equivalent to

```
c = c + 1
f(c);
```

whereas `f(c+1)` is equivalent to

```
auto d = c + 1;
f(d);
```

And just for completeness: `f(c++)` is the same like

```
f(c);
c = c+1;
```

However sequence points matter, e.g. `if(c++ > 0 && c++ < 10)` would evaluate like

```
auto a = c;
c = c + 1;

auto b = c;
c = c + 1;

if(a > 0 || b < 10) { /* ... */ }
```

and consequently preincrement

```
c = c + 1;
auto a = c;

c = c + 1;
auto b = c;

if(a > 0 || b < 10) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Use `char` instead of `auto`, to turn it from pseudo-C to C.

Comment: By the way `f(c++, c++)` is undefined behavior, for modifying `c` twice without a sequence point.

Comment: in C, `auto a = c` is the same as `int a = c` regardless of the type of `c`.  Yay implicit int.

Comment: @Zack: I know about this, however I wanted to avoid using a specific type to keep focus purely on variable names, yet make it clear this is in a local scope.

Answer (score 3):

Calling with `c + 1` won't change the value of `c` in the local context (the one used when printing `*c`), but using `++c` in the call will.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**: You shouldn't use increment operator. Operator+ would be better.:

```
reverse(c + 1);
printf("%c", *c);
```

Comment: I thought that, but then all that would arguably do would be print the string out in its original order. the reason this would reverse it is the fact that it gets to the end and then returns from each function printing out as it went.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't do the same thing.

It increments it then sends it to your function.

Answer (score 0):

when you put `c+1`, it doesn't change the value of `c`, but `++c` does change the value of `c`.. as an example for difference between pre and post increment operators:

```
int a = 1; 
int b = ++a; 
// Now a is 2 and b is also 2. 

int a = 1; 
int b = a++; 
// Now a is 2 but b is 1.
```